# ShareActionProvider for API level less than 14

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

is it possible to use shareActionProvider for Apps using API less than 14?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is now possible to do this using the v7 support library.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use it on pre ICS SDK maybe using v4 support library, see this topic [Cross version ShareActionProvider support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/1W2TiP1zD3s/kA-fP3Xu25IJ) You can use [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) to support older versions, see this example [ShareActionProviders.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ShareActionProviders.java)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone faces frustration in finding what libary to import (not very clear reading off the documentation):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

One thing that I guess, gives you a clue is the URL of the docs you are looking at, which I believe corresponds to the API structure:

[image]

For myself, this has so far worked for the compatibility-library-related docs.